# rsyslog to AWS ELB logstash - DNS TTL issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, dns, logstash, rsyslog

I have a 3 node elasticsearch cluster in AWS ( behind an ELB )
I have a logstash instance also behind an ELB. This ELB forwards TCP 5140 to the logstash instance which does some simple filters and forwards to the elasticsearch ELB and thence into elasticsearch. The JRE on the logstash instance has networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 to force the JVM to re-resolve the upstream ELB IP.

On clients i have:
*.*     @@logstash.elb.name:5140

to forward events to the logstash ELB. This is TCP as ELB cannot forward UDP.

This works for an unspecified time and then fails to forward events. I'm suspecting that rsyslog doesn't honor the TTL on the ELB name and as the ELB Ip's are regularly rolled over it's connecting to a stale address.

I found one old post suggesting kill -HUP every 5 minutes to force rsyslog to DNS re-resolve. This seems a bit lame.

It's an issue because i have noted if rsyslog blocks due unable to deliver ( a reality as it's using TCP rather than UDP ) then the caller will block. Nginx for example will completely block if unable to log to syslog as it doesn't want to lose logs.

Any thoughts/comments on my setup appreciated...

Comment: I wonder if RebindInterval or the KeepAlive* options will force rsyslog to re-establish the connection. See http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfwd.html for more details

Comment: thankyou - wasn't aware of those options - let me have a look. If it does a new DNS lookup when the RebindInterval expires it might work...

Comment: You're welcome. Now I realize I forgot to mention that you may have to upgrade rsyslog, as some of these options were introduced recently.